# I get 'buildCompatibilityCheck' error on WebGL Build made with Unity 2019. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

There is a problem when starting a build for WebGL made with Unity 2019. Every time I try to play it the browser shows an alert saying:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'buildCompatibilityCheck'`

The build is generated without any problem and within Unity it works as it should.

When I test a mirror version of the project in Unity 2018 the build works. So it seems like the problem comes with Unity 2019 as it happens with every WebGL build made with this version.

Why is this happening? and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have a WebGL game that's live that was made in 2019.3. There must be a specific feature that's changed between versions of Unity.

Comment: I see. I am using 2019.3 as well. Do you have an idea of what could be causing this "buildCompatibilityCheck" ?

Comment: Also, I am not that familiar with Unity, and the version that I have installed is older, but are you using any external add-on/plugin/asset/idunno? Anything that could be responsible that is not "Unity" itself? Does the console error have a call stack log? If I have time I'll update my Unity and investigate a bit, I have been wanting to tinker with it for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll change the title.
No, I am not using anything more than Unity.

The only error displayed on the browser's console is this one. I have the full strack trace exceptions enabled.
Also everything seems fine with the WebGL Build Support module.
I am confused but still searching for a solution. Thanks for your responce.

Comment: @damix911 sometimes it feels like someone just goes though the unity3d tag downvoting everything.

Comment: @Rocketman Dan: Aw man, that sucks, sorry to hear about that!
- Anonymous downvoter: let's be friends!
- Jorge Isaac: I am installing 2019.3 so I can try this out first hand.

Comment: @Jorge Isaac. I can't repro. Unity is version `2019.3.14f1 Personal`. How are you running your WebGL build? Opening the `index.html` file with a browser is likely _not_ work but you should get a warning if you try to do it. You need a web server to serve your game. I did `C:\Users\dari8942\Desktop\Programming\Unity\BuildErrorRepro\Builds\WebGL>python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the folder that has the `index.html` file and then I pointed my browser to `http://localhost:8000/` and everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: `Every time I try to play it the browser shows an alert saying`
We need more details about how you are starting the game. I think this is key to understanding the problem.

Comment: I'm using the "better template" from greggman with some personal modifications to make the index.html. Here is the link: https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template.
For testing I play the builds directly from the contain folder using "Microsoft Edge" if it runs, then I upload it to a server where with a route me and other people can access and play it. I do this to all the builds.
However both of this methods throw the 'buildCompatibilityCheck' error with Unity 2019. Every time I do it with 2018 works perfectly fine.
Thanks for your responce. I hope this information could help.

Comment: I just tried to use the default WebGL template on the build, because I was suspecting if some of my modifications on the template could cause problems with Unity 2019.
But no, still getting the 'buildCompatibilityCheck' error.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Okay this is far fetched: did you edit code with Visual Studio at any time? Did you get any warning about .Net version mismatch? Could it be a problem with Windows? Are you up to date with .Net Framework/browsers etc.?

Comment: Could you post the generated files somewhere? I think what I would really like to see are the generated `UnityLoader.js` and `index.html`.

Comment: Also, try other browsers and see if the message is any different. Judging from the log you posted I think you are using Edge. Try Chrome or Firefox if possible.

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio with all the scripts and never got any warning of .Net. Unfortunately I can't share the index.html but as I said the default Unity template doesn't work either. I used Chrome for testing the game from the server and throw again the same error. I can't find a way to making it work.
I'll try to make the build from another PC yeah, and let you know if that fixed something. 
Thanks again for your responce, means a lot.

Comment: It didn´t worked. So that means the problem might be within the project. Still do some testing.